# Quantitative Model classification

Tags: models

In the world of Quantitative `model risk management`, can you please tell me what is `Model 1` type, `Model 2` type etc?

Comment: Where do you see these - model 1, 2 type?

Comment: I have heard in a technical discussion on model risk management

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall hearing these terms. May be local to your firm. I suggest you look for its model risk management policies / procedures / training on its intranet, or ask whoever said it what they mean and where these terms are defined.